# User defined fields in graphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphene-django

Making an employee management system with graphene-Django and I have a JsonB field that I don't know the shape of because each company will defined the shape.

Here's the model:

```
    class Employee(models.Model):
        bonuses = models.JSONField(default=dict)
        #...OTHER FIELDS
```

here's the type:

```
    class EmployeeType(DjangoObjectType):
        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = "__all__"
```

Here's the mutation class:

```
    class EmployeeInfo(graphene.Mutation):

        employee = graphene.List(EmployeeType)

        class Arguments:
            bonuses = GenericScalar()
            #...OTHER FIELDS

        def mutate(self, info, **kwargs):
             #DOING STUFF
            return EmployeeInfo(employee=employee)
```

Now, say a company wants to give bonuses to a developer with the following schema:

```
    export const EMPLOYEE_INFO = gql`
        mutation MutateEmployee(
                    $employeeOfTheMonth: Int
                    $mostPR: Int
                    $profitSharing: Int
        ) {
            employeeInfo(
                bonuses:{
                    employeeOfTheMonth: $employeeOfTheMonth
                    mostPR: $mostPR
                    profitSharing: $profitSharing
                }
                #...OTHER FIELDS
            ){....}
         }
     `
```

This is my current setup, the problem is I get only null values in the database for the bonuses field. Notice that I'm using `GenericScalar` which is not documented and I don't know if that's the wrong scalar.

If this is a restaurant, obviously the bonuses will be different and that's why I need a setup like this.

How can I define a field that will take user defined shapes?

Comment: You should try JSONString type for that argument: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/scalars/#graphene-jsonstring

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```py
    class EmployeeInfo(graphene.Mutation):

        employee = graphene.List(EmployeeType)

        class Arguments:
            bonuses = graphene.JSONString()
            #...OTHER FIELDS
```